# How to make log in failed Error handled in blazor?

Tags: azure, sql-server-2008, blazor

App was published to azure portal. But free service is terminated and I got no access to sqldatabase in azure portal. Is there any way to get rid of error which caused by connection failed? I got other service available by the end of year except database service.

thanks
Joon

Answer (score 1):

See what the error is and wrap the logic that returns the error in a try catch and catch the error.